# CASE Expression returning NULL when with other case statements, returns expected result when alone

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

When i run this line of code alone i get the expected result of 1:

```
sum(case when facilityname like '%AT%' then count(status) else 0 end) as AT_all_status
```

However when i run with multiple case statements together as shown in this example all case statements return NULL:

```
sum(case when facilityname like '%AT%' then count(status) else 0 end) as AT_all_status,
sum(case when facilityname like '%AT%' and status in ('Current','Approved') then count(status) else 0 end) as AT_approved_current,
sum(case when facilityname like '%CZ%' then count(status) else 0 end) as CZ_all_status,
sum(case when facilityname like '%CZ%' and status in ('Current','Approved') then count(status) else 0 end) as CZ_approved_current,
sum(case when facilityname like '%FGE%' then count(status) else 0 end) as FGE_all_status,
sum(case when facilityname like '%FGE%' and status in ('Current','Approved') then count(status) else 0 end) as FGE_approved_current,
sum(case when facilityname like '%FRA%' then count(status) else 0 end) as FRA_all_status,
sum(case when facilityname like '%FRA%' and status in ('Current','Approved') then count(status) else 0 end) as FRA_approved_current
```

When they should actually be returning their own numbers, and do so when ran alone, is there a case statement behaviour i'm missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way to translate your query using only one aggregate function and don't nest it is the following:

```
count(case when facilityname like '%AT%' then status end)
```

Answer (score 2):

In standard SQL, this should not return any results (other than an error):

```
sum(case when facilityname like '%AT%' then count(status) else 0 end) as AT_all_status
```

because aggregation functions cannot be nested.  Oracle does allow nesting them, but I don't commend using that functionality -- a subquery is simple enough.

In any case, I'm pretty sure that you actually intend:

```
sum(case when facilityname like '%AT%' then 1 else 0 end) as AT_all_status
```

Comment: I think `sum(case when facilityname like '%AT%' and status is not null then 1 else 0 end) as AT_all_status` is the proper conversion, but otherwise you're abolutely right...

Comment: Actually the returning of 1 or 0 would not be useful here as i'm trying to actually count the amount of statuses, so it could be any number. What alternative would you recommend if this is bad practice?

Comment: `count(DISTINCT case when facilityname like '%AT%' then status end)`?

Comment: sum(count(case when facilityname like '%AT%' then status end)) ended up being exactly what i needed, but you help me come to it. Thanks! Post as an answer if you wish.